# RxClojure - What's the difference between rx/return and rx/observable*?

Tags: clojure, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm reading the book [Clojure Reactive Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UKUVN7Y)(which is great BTW), but I can't get my head around the difference between those 2 code samples which create a simple Observables:

```
(ns rx-playground.core
    (:require [rx.lang.clojure.core :as rx]) 
    (:import [rx Observable]))

;; Sample 1
(defn simple-obs-one [n] (rx/return n))

;; Sample 2
(defn simple-obs-two [n]
    (rx/observable*
        (fn [observer]
        (rx/on-next observer n)
        (rx/on-completed observer))))
```

The only thing I've noticed is that the first sample returns an object of type:

```
rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable
```

when the second piece of code return an object of type:

```
rx.Observable
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who can shed the light on that question.

Answer (score 3):

Both cases are returning an Observable and for this particular example both do the same thing: emit one value.

`simple-obs-two` is an example how you would build rx/return if there was no built-in rx/return in the rx library.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @dAni.